# axis labels on y-axis only using xyplot in R

Tags: r, plot, axis, label

Relatively new to site and r so please forgive any protocols I may not adhere to.

I am producing a plot with xyplot. My code

```
library(lattice)

height <- c(1,3,5)
mass <- c(10, 12, 14)

d <- data.frame (height,mass)

xyplot(height ~ mass, type = 'a', scales = list(alternating = 1, tck = c(1,0)))
```

and I get this

[image: Image of plot is here]

My problem is that I cannot remove the labels from the x-axis so only the y-axis ticks are labelled. This is so I can stack a number of plots with data.arrange. I have looked here and on other places online and found some answers but I clearly do not understand the code because I still cannot do it. I have tried removing the axes and rebuilding with "scales" to no success.

Can someone please assist me with this?

Regards
Aaron

Answer (score 0):

Inside the `scales` argument you can add a list for the attributes of the x-axis and set `labels=NULL`. For additional options, see the `scales` section in the help for `xyplot`. I've also removed the x-axis title since you probably won't want that repeated for each graph either:

```
xyplot(height ~ mass, type ='a', xlab="", 
       scales=list(alternating=1, tck=c(1,0), x=list(labels=NULL)))
```

[image]